# Unable to write to MT25QU256 from Arria 10 SOM

Tags: fpga, flash, intel-fpga, intel, nios-ii

I am using module Arria 10 SOM by iWave with IC Flash MT25QU256. I am trying to read and write from NIOS II processor to different sectors of this flash.

Currently, I'm using the IP Core Generic Quad SPI Controller II from Quartus Prime 18.1 Standard IP Core. In NIOS II software program, I'm using APIs from HAL (alt_qspi_controller2_write and alt_qspi_controller2_read) to read and write to this flash. My simple program writes a value (0x1234578) to sector 504 (the flash contains 512 sectors with 64KB each) and reads back from this sector. But the result from the reading returns 0xFFFFFFFF, so that I think that I didn't write to the flash successfully. Also I tried to write different sectors with the same method but still returns the same result.

Is this an error from the IP Core ? I read from the core user guide that it is compatible with Micron's flash devices. So if it really is, what IP Core should I use to read and write to Micron's flash devices ?

Comment: Could you post the parameters you've used for the IP core  along with the snippet of code you are using in Nios. Also could you try writing twice to the same address and then reading back (don't ask why you might have to, it's a great IP core, honest...).

Answer (score 0):

We use that IP core with an Arria 10, albeit with an MT25QU512 devices.

[image: Parameters in Qsys]

I remember it being a pain in the **** to get working properly. Somewhere in either the FPGA IP core or the HAL driver there is a bug that I never could pin down, but essentially it resulted in having to issue all write commands twice in order for them to stick. I seem to recall the HAL driver does the twice write trick but was doing it wrong IIRC.

I ended up basically writing my own driver for programming the flash. I've stripped it out from a larger software driver (haven't tried compiling the stripped down version) and attached below.

There are four main APIs:

- `bu_initialiseFlashDevice()` is called first to check that the device was correctly detected based on it's silicon ID.
- `bu_readFlash()` is for reading one or more 32bit values from a given address.
- `bu_eraseFlash()` erases a given address range.
- `bu_programFlash()` is for writing one or more 32bit values at a given address after it has been erased (must erase before write).

In all the functions, addresses and lengths are specified in bytes, so must be a multiple of `sizeof(uint32_t)` (this is checked).

The `base` argument is the base address that Nios accesses `avl_mem` port at, and the `csr_base` argument is the base address that the `avl_csr` port is located.

```
/*
 * BoardUpdateEPCQLFlash.c
 *
 *  Created on: Apr 25, 2018
 *      Author: Thomas Carpenter
 *
 */

#include <stdint.h>

// Specify memory size in Megabit (128/256/512/1024)
#define MEMORY_SIZE_Mb    256

#define BU_FLASH_BLOCK_SIZE        (64UL*1024UL)
#define BU_FLASH_MEMORY_SIZE       ((MEMORY_SIZE_Mb*1024UL*1024UL)/8UL)
#define BU_FLASH_WORD_SIZE         (sizeof(uint32_t))
#define BU_FLASH_WORD_MASK         (BU_FLASH_WORD_SIZE - 1UL)
#define BU_FLASH_BLOCK_MASK        (BU_FLASH_BLOCK_SIZE - 1UL)
#define BU_FLASH_BLOCK_COUNT       (BU_FLASH_MEMORY_SIZE/BU_FLASH_BLOCK_SIZE)

//Memory Status Register
#define QSPI_STATUS_REG             (0x00)

#define STATUS_WIP_MASK             (0x00000001)
#define STATUS_WIP_AVAILABLE        (0x00000000)
#define STATUS_WIP_BUSY             (0x00000001)

#define QSPI_WRITE_POLLING_LIMIT    (1000000UL)
#define QSPI_ERASE_POLLING_LIMIT    (100000000UL)

//Memory ID Register
#define QSPI_RDID_REG               (0x08)

#define RDID_MASK                   (0x000000FF)

#define RDID_QSPI128                (0x00000018)
#define RDID_QSPI256                (0x00000019)
#define RDID_QSPI512                (0x00000020)
#define RDID_QSPI1024               (0x00000021)

#define RDID_QSPIxx(xx) RDID_QSPI##xx
#define RDID_QSPIx(x) RDID_QSPIxx(x)
#define RDID_QSPI RDID_QSPIx(MEMORY_SIZE_Mb)

//Memory Command Register
#define QSPI_MEM_OP_REG             (0x0C)

#define MEM_OP_CMD_MASK             (0x00000003)
#define MEM_OP_BULK_ERASE_CMD       (0x00000001)
#define MEM_OP_SECTOR_ERASE_CMD     (0x00000002)
#define MEM_OP_SECTOR_PROTECT_CMD   (0x00000003)
#define MEM_OP_WRITE_ENABLE_CMD     (0x00000004)

#define MEM_OP_SECTOR_SHIFT         (0x8)
#define MEM_OP_SECTOR_MASK          (0x0000FFFF << (MEM_OP_SECTOR_SHIFT))

//ISR Register
#define QSPI_ISR_REG                (0x10)

#define ISR_ILLEGAL_ERASE_MASK      (0x00000001)
#define ISR_ILLEGAL_ERASE_ACTIVE    (0x00000001)
#define ISR_ILLEGAL_WRITE_MASK      (0x00000002)
#define ISR_ILLEGAL_WRITE_ACTIVE    (0x00000002)

static inline void short_delay(uint32_t i) {
    while (i--) {
        asm volatile ("nop");
    }
}


//Convert byte address to erase block offset in bytes
static inline uint32_t bu_getBlockOffset(uint32_t address) {
    return (address & BU_FLASH_BLOCK_MASK);
}

//Convert byte address to erase block address in bytes
static inline uint32_t bu_getBlockAddress(uint32_t address) {
    return (address & ~BU_FLASH_BLOCK_MASK);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// bu_waitForOperationDone
//
// When you issue a command to the flash, you read-back the "status"
// register to see if the operation has finished.  Bit 7 of the
// "status" register indicates "done;" other bits indicate various
// kinds of errors.
//
// This function returns zero if successful (operation finished, error-
// free, within the given timeout-interval), and nonzero if there is
// an error.
//
// A timeout results in a negative return value.
//
// If a device-error occurs, the value of the status-register is
// returned.
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int32_t bu_waitForOperationDone(uint32_t* csr_base, uint32_t retryCount) {
    uint32_t retryCounter = 0;
    do {
        uint32_t status = IORD_32DIRECT(csr_base, QSPI_STATUS_REG);
        if ((status & STATUS_WIP_MASK) == STATUS_WIP_AVAILABLE) {
            // Done, no error.
            return 0;
        }
        short_delay(1000); //Add short delay to avoid spamming the Avalon-MM bus.
    } while (retryCounter++ < retryCount); //Keep checking until either the op is done, or we timed out.

    return -1;
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// bu_programFlashBuffer
//
// Executes ONE complete block write sequence to the flash.
// The result is either:
//
//     * 'length' words written to the flash successfully, or
//     * an error-code.
//
// It is the caller's responsibility to make sure the region of flash
// at "offset" is erased prior to calling this function.  You may not
// use this function to write more than FLASH_BLOCK_SIZE bytes at a time.
//
// The address + length combo should not cross a FLASH_BLOCK_SIZE boundary.
//
// You may NOT call this function to program a region which spans a
// block-boundary.  Well: You CAN, but it will result in an error.
//
// Returns 0 if successful; -1 for a timeout; -2 for an invalid
// buffer; or the status register value if an error.
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int32_t __attribute__ ((noinline)) bu_programFlashBuffer(uint32_t* base, uint32_t* csr_base, uint32_t address, const uint32_t* data, uint32_t length, uint32_t programRetry) {
    //First make sure the write is allowed (no boundary issues)
    if ((address & BU_FLASH_WORD_MASK) || (length & BU_FLASH_WORD_MASK)) {
        return -3; //Address/Length not aligned to BU_FLASH_WORD_SIZE.
    } else if (length > BU_FLASH_BLOCK_SIZE) {
        return -2; //Invalid length
    } else if (((address + length - 1) & (uint32_t) ~BU_FLASH_BLOCK_MASK) != (address & (uint32_t) ~BU_FLASH_BLOCK_MASK)) {
        return -2; //Crossed a buffer boundary
    }
    
    //For each word
    while (length) {
        //Write the next word
        uint32_t byte = IORD_32DIRECT(data, 0);//Read from PCIe buffer
        IOWR_32DIRECT(base, address, byte);  //Copy the data to the Flash buffer
        //Wait for write to complete.
        int32_t status = bu_waitForOperationDone(csr_base, programRetry);
        if (status != 0) {
            return status;
        }
#ifndef ALTERA_IP_CORE_IS_NO_LONGER_UTTERLY_xxxx
        //Write again as sometimes it skips the first write.
        IOWR_32DIRECT(base, address, byte);  //Copy the data to the Flash buffer
        //Wait for write to complete.
        status = bu_waitForOperationDone(csr_base, programRetry);
        if (status != 0) {
            return status;
        }
#endif
        //Check if the write was a success
        uint32_t isr_reg = IORD_32DIRECT(csr_base, QSPI_ISR_REG);
        if ((isr_reg & ISR_ILLEGAL_WRITE_MASK) == ISR_ILLEGAL_WRITE_ACTIVE) {
            //If an illegal write flag occurred
            //Clear the flag
            IOWR_32DIRECT(csr_base, QSPI_ISR_REG, ISR_ILLEGAL_WRITE_ACTIVE);
            //Then return the error
            return ISR_ILLEGAL_WRITE_ACTIVE;
        }
        //One more word sent.
        address += BU_FLASH_WORD_SIZE;
        length -= BU_FLASH_WORD_SIZE;
        data++;
    }
    
    //Done.
    return 0;
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// bu_programFlash
//
// Programs 'length' bytes from 'data' into a contiguous region
// of flash at the specified 'address'
//
// The region of flash must have been previously erased.
//
// The region of flash can span any number of erase-block boundaries.
//
// This function separates the incoming buffer into blocks and
// then uses bu_programFlashBlock to write each block.
//
// Returns 0 if successful; -1 for a timeout; -2 for an invalid
// buffer; -3 if the address or length are not aligned correctly;
// or the status register value if an error.
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int32_t bu_programFlash(uint32_t* base, uint32_t* csr_base, uint32_t address, const uint32_t* data, uint32_t length) {
    int32_t status;
    if ((address & BU_FLASH_WORD_MASK) || (length & BU_FLASH_WORD_MASK)) {
        return -3; //Address/Length are not aligned to BU_FLASH_WORD_SIZE.
    }
    
    while (length > 0) {
        //Determine the maximum length for this block
        uint32_t blockLength = BU_FLASH_BLOCK_SIZE - bu_getBlockOffset(address); //maximum length is distance between block boundary and current offset in block
        //If there is less to send than there is room, limit the block length
        if (blockLength > length) {
            blockLength = length;
        }
        //Program the block
        status = bu_programFlashBuffer(base, csr_base, address, data, blockLength, QSPI_WRITE_POLLING_LIMIT);
        if (status != 0) {
            return status; //Failed to program block
        }
        //And move on to the next block
        length -= blockLength;
        address += blockLength;
        data += (blockLength / BU_FLASH_WORD_SIZE);
    }
    return 0;
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// flash_erase_block
//
// Erase the single block of flash which contains the BYTE-offset
// "offset."
//
// Returns zero if successful, negative for timeout, or
// status-register value for device-error.
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int32_t __attribute__ ((noinline)) bu_eraseFlashBlock(uint32_t* csr_base, uint32_t address, uint32_t eraseRetry) {
    int32_t status;
    //Check that device not busy
    status = bu_waitForOperationDone(csr_base, eraseRetry);
    if (status != 0) {
        //Device busy. Give up and return.
        return status;
    }
    //Calculate Mem Op Command Sector Field
    uint32_t sector = (address/BU_FLASH_BLOCK_SIZE);
    uint32_t sectorCommand = ((sector << MEM_OP_SECTOR_SHIFT) & MEM_OP_SECTOR_MASK);
    //Send Write-Enable Request
    uint32_t weCommand = sectorCommand | MEM_OP_WRITE_ENABLE_CMD;
    IOWR_32DIRECT(csr_base, QSPI_MEM_OP_REG, weCommand);
    //Perform Sector Erase
    uint32_t seCommand = sectorCommand | MEM_OP_SECTOR_ERASE_CMD;
    IOWR_32DIRECT(csr_base, QSPI_MEM_OP_REG, seCommand);
    //And wait for it to complete
    status = bu_waitForOperationDone(csr_base, eraseRetry);
    if (status != 0) {
        //Device busy. Give up and return.
        return status;
    }
    //Check if erase was success
    uint32_t isr_reg = IORD_32DIRECT(csr_base, QSPI_ISR_REG);
    if ((isr_reg & ISR_ILLEGAL_ERASE_MASK) == ISR_ILLEGAL_ERASE_ACTIVE) {
        //If an illegal erase flag occurred
        //Clear the flag
        IOWR_32DIRECT(csr_base, QSPI_ISR_REG, ISR_ILLEGAL_ERASE_ACTIVE);
        //Then return the error
        return ISR_ILLEGAL_ERASE_ACTIVE;
    }
    //Otherwise success.
    return 0;
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// bu_eraseFlash
//
// Erase all of the blocks which intersect with the given range
// (address + length).  This just calls bu_eraseFlashBlock enough
// times to do the job.
//
// Returns 0 if successful; -1 for a timeout; -3 if the address
// or length are not aligned correctly; or the status register
// value if an error.
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int32_t bu_eraseFlash(uint32_t* base, uint32_t* csr_base, uint32_t address, uint32_t length) {
    int32_t status;
    if ((address & BU_FLASH_WORD_MASK) || (length & BU_FLASH_WORD_MASK)) {
        return -3; //Address/Length not aligned to BU_FLASH_WORD_SIZE.
    }

    while (length > 0) {
        //Determine the maximum length for this block
        uint32_t blockLength = BU_FLASH_BLOCK_SIZE - bu_getBlockOffset(address); //maximum length is distance between block boundary and current offset in block
        //If there is less to send than there is room, limit the block length
        if (blockLength > length) {
            blockLength = length;
        }
        //Erase the block
        status = bu_eraseFlashBlock(csr_base, address, QSPI_ERASE_POLLING_LIMIT);
        if (status != 0) {
            return status; //Failed to erase block
        }
        //Perform a write-read, just to make sure that the sector erase completed well
        //and the useless Altera IP core is back in a sensible mode.
        IOWR_32DIRECT(base, address, 0xFFFFFFFF);
        uint32_t actual = IORD_32DIRECT(base, address);
        //Check if they are the same
        if (actual != 0xFFFFFFFF) {
            //If the value is not empty, return the address we failed at
            return address+BU_FLASH_WORD_SIZE-1; //Return address of end of flash word, so that we never return 0.
        }
        //And move on to the next block
        length -= blockLength;
        address += blockLength;
    }
    return 0;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// bu_verifyFlash
//
// Reads each address in turn and compares it to the data buffer.
// If the value doesn't match, the function returns the address
// where the compare failed. If the entire buffer is a match, the
// address 0 is returned. If the address which fails happens to
// be zero, then 1 is returned to avoid confusion.
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
uint32_t bu_verifyFlash(uint32_t* base, uint32_t* csr_base, uint32_t address, const uint32_t * data, uint32_t length) {
    if ((address & BU_FLASH_WORD_MASK) || (length & BU_FLASH_WORD_MASK)) {
        return -3; //Address/Length not aligned to BU_FLASH_WORD_SIZE.
    }
    //For each word
    while (length) {
        //Get the expected value from the buffer (and move the pointer on for next time)
        uint32_t expected = IORD_32DIRECT(data, 0);
        //Read the actual value from the flash
        uint32_t actual = IORD_32DIRECT(base, address);
        //Check if they are the same
        if (expected != actual) {
            //If the value is not as expected, return the address we failed at
            return address+BU_FLASH_WORD_SIZE-1; //Return address of end of flash word, so that we never return 0.
        }
        address += BU_FLASH_WORD_SIZE;
        length -= BU_FLASH_WORD_SIZE;
        data++;
    }
    return 0; //Success, everything verified correctly.
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// bu_readFlash
//
// Reads each address in turn and stores it to the data buffer.
//
// Returns 0 if successful; or -3 if the address or length are
// not aligned correctly
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int32_t bu_readFlash(uint32_t* base, uint32_t* csr_base, uint32_t address, uint32_t * data, uint32_t length) {
    if ((address & BU_FLASH_WORD_MASK) || (length & BU_FLASH_WORD_MASK)) {
        return -3; //Address/Length not aligned to BU_FLASH_WORD_SIZE.
    }
    //For each word
    while (length) {
        //Read the actual value from the flash
        uint32_t actual = IORD_32DIRECT(base, address);
        //Store to the read buffer
        IOWR_32DIRECT(data, 0, actual);
        //Update address and data pointers
        address += BU_FLASH_WORD_SIZE;
        length -= BU_FLASH_WORD_SIZE;
        data++;
    }
    return 0; //Success, everything verified correctly.
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// bu_initialiseFlashDevice
//
// Performs any initialisation tasks. Returns 0 if successful.
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int32_t bu_initialiseFlashDevice(uint32_t* base, uint32_t* csr_base) {
    //Read Device ID
    uint32_t silicon_id = IORD_32DIRECT(csr_base,QSPI_RDID_REG);
    silicon_id = (silicon_id >> 16) & RDID_MASK;
    //Check if the correct device.
    if (silicon_id != RDID_QSPI) {
        return -1; //Invalid EPCQL device.
    } 
    return 0; //Success.
}
```

Comment: Is the MT25QU512 used as the Arria 10 configuration flash? While I haven't used an Arria 10, with Xilinx-7 series devices did encounter an issue in the Xilinx AXI Quad SPI 3.2 when the IP core was used to access the configuration flash, in that the first SPI command after the FPGA configuration failed - see [AXI Quad SPI clock polarity 1 incorrect timing](https://support.xilinx.com/s/question/0D54U00005Seaj3SAB/axi-quad-spi-clock-polarity-1-incorrect-timing?language=en_US). Not sure if that helps to provide debugging suggestions with the Arria 10 IP.

Comment: @ChesterGillon yes, in my case its used as the config flash. It's connected via the FPGAs hard ASMI controller (serial config flash). The Quad SPI core acts as a wrapper on top of the ASMI block and clearly has some design issue.